# Django3 multiple files submit to database

Tags: django, django-3.2

I actually had an idea to make an app where a bulk of files upload can be possible at once, but I got some difficulties on how to implement that on the model and for now I'm in need of help.

And I'm currently trying to solve this error.

I get these errors:

```
Internal Server Error: /upload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/records/views.py", line 123, in send_files
    form.save()
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 460, in save
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The GoCustomerRegistration could not be created because the data didn't validate.
[25/Aug/2021 13:02:31] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 500 70627
Internal Server Error: /upload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/records/views.py", line 123, in send_files
    form.save()
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 460, in save
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The GoCustomerRegistration could not be created because the data didn't validate.
[25/Aug/2021 13:06:28] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 500 70627
Internal Server Error: /upload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/records/views.py", line 123, in send_files
    form.save()
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 460, in save
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The GoCustomerRegistration could not be created because the data didn't validate.
[25/Aug/2021 13:06:30] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 500 70627
[25/Aug/2021 13:06:34] "GET /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 1906
Internal Server Error: /upload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/records/views.py", line 123, in send_files
    form.save()
  File "/home/yokwejuste/PycharmProjects/DjangoProjects/Internship/go_immigration/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 460, in save
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The GoCustomerRegistration could not be created because the data didn't validate.
[25/Aug/2021 13:06:58] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 500 70641
```

Models.py:

```
class GoCustomerRegistration(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Full name')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Customer Type')
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Destination')
    time_of_submission = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
    registered_by = models.ForeignKey(GoUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Age", null=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(max_length=10000, verbose_name='Customer Picture',
                          default='profile1.png', upload_to='customers/profiles/')
    documents = models.FileField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='Documents',
                             null=False, default=None,
                             upload_to=f'customers/files/%Y/%m/%d')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["time_of_submission"]
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s --- %s' % (self.name, self.documents)
```

Views.py:

```
def send_files(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = GoCustomerRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            return redirect('preview')
        else:
            HttpResponse(f'Invalid data { request.user.username }')
        context['document_form'] = form

    else:
        form = GoCustomerRegistrationForm
        context['document_form'] = form

    return render(request, 'files.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
path('upload', send_files, name='upload'),
```

forms.py:

```
class GoCustomerRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GoCustomerRegistration
        fields = ('name', 'type', 'destination', 'age', 'photo', 'documents')
        TYPE_CHOICES = (
            ('', 'Select a customer type'),
            ('student', 'STUDENT'),
            ('worker', 'WORKER'),
            ('tourist', 'TOURIST'),)
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user'}),
            'age': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user'}),
            'type': forms.Select(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user'}),
            'destination': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user'}),
            'photo': forms.ClearableFileInput(
            attrs={'multiple': True, 'class': 'btn btn-primary d - block btn - user w - 100'}),
            'documents': forms.ClearableFileInput(
            attrs={'multiple': True, 'class': 'btn btn-primary d - block btn - user w - 100'}),
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In your **views.py** it should be `form.is_valid()` not `form.is_valid` and try to ask one question at a time. SO is the first place to look for an answer but the last place to post one(your last resort...) try your best to solve it yourself first by reading doc or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want assign multiple file to a model, you should make a separated model and make a FK between them. E.g for photo:

```py
class GoCustomerRegistration(models.Model):
    ...


class CustomerPhoto(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='customers/profiles/')
```

Now each customer can has multiple photos

And now for uploading multiple image in template, you can use `InlineFormSet`. Docs in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: What about the ValueError I'm getting at each time I want to submit using this code above, added to the fact that I wish to a bulk upload...?